# How can I filter the post using parent category and child category in admin list in Wordpress

Tags: categories, filters

I need to make the two dropdown 1. parent category and 2. Child category. When user select the parent category, only child of that category will be displayed in second dropdown and after selecting it, the post of them will be displayed in admin list.

Comment: Related question: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/417404/how-to-show-sub-taxonomies-based-on-selected-parent-taxonomy