# How to show sub-taxonomies based on selected parent-taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I have have a custom post type: "cars" for car spec and its taxonomy "cars-brand"

Because the number of taxonomies and sub-taxonomies is very large, it is difficult to choose it in post edit page.

```
bmw
  -series1
    --F20
    --G40
  -series2 
    --F22
    --G42
benz
  -Aclass 
    --W176
    --W177
  -Cclass
    --W203
    --W204
```

I'm trying to display only those sub-taxonomies of selected parent taxonomy (not all the sub-taxonomies from other parent taxonomies). For example, if I select BMW from the first dropdown, then second dropdown should only display the series1 and series2, then if I select series1 from secend dropdown shoud only desplay F20 and F40.

In [this Question](https://I%27m%20trying%20to%20display%20only%20those%20sub-taxonomies%20of%20selected%20parent%20taxonomy%20(not%20all%20the%20sub-taxonomies%20from%20other%20parent%20taxonomies).%20For%20example,%20if%20I%20select%20a%20parent%20taxonomy%20from%20the%20first%20dropdown,%20then%20second%20dropdown%20should%20only%20display%20the%20sub-taxonomies%20of%20it.) used for user page, Is it possible to advise on how to use this item?

Comment: Related question: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/417396/how-can-i-filter-the-post-using-parent-category-and-child-category-in-admin-list